# How to display object properties within console.table

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I want to display the char properties in the table how can i do this? it currently logs the whole object and is undefined when i use console.table(tileGridArray.char)

```
    const tileGridArray = [];


for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 3; rowIndex++) { // Loop through each row
    const row = [];

    for (let colIndex = 0; colIndex < 3; colIndex++) { // Loop through each column in the current row
        const tileObj = {
        row: rowIndex,
        col: colIndex,
        type: null, // mine true of false
        visibility: null,
        char: 'why'
    };

    row.push(tileObj);
    }

    tileGridArray.push(row); }


console.table(tileGridArray)
```

Comment: What result do you expect exactly?

Comment: it looks like your pushing a matrix, not an array. is that on purpose? what's your expected result? seeing all the tileObjects in a table?

Comment: I want to see each tileObj char displayed in the table. essentially this is mine sweeper in the console and that char will be replaced with a * that represents a mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display only the `char` property in the table, you can create a new array that contains only the char property of each object in `tileGridArray`, and then pass that array to `console.table()`.

```js
const charArray = tileGridArray
  .map((row) => row.map((tileObj) => tileObj.char));
console.table(charArray);
```

If you want to show all tile objects flat, just flatten the array before printing it:

```js
const charArray = tileGridArray
  .map((row) => row.map((tileObj) => tileObj.char))
  .flat();
console.table(charArray);
```

check out the [MDN docs for more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/table#collections_of_primitive_types)

Comment: good work, man! fixed a small issue in your answer and changed the formatting a little to be more readable.